# Prolog check if a or b exists in facts

Tags: prolog

I want to write a rule that allows me to check whether a movie or an actor exists in the given facts.

Example facts

```
starsin(ice_age,compton__doug).
starsin(hulk,wryn__rhiannon_leigh).
starsin(hulk,turman__john).
starsin(hook,mcnatt__adam).
```

Query Input

```
?- exists(ice_age).
true.
?- exists(turman_john).
true
?- exists(bob).
false
```

Rule written

```
exists(Movie,Actor) :- starsin(Movie,Actor).
```

My problem is my rule is that it doesn't check movie or actor. I am forced to type in the query:

```
?- exists(hulk,Y) or exists(X,turman_john)
```

I want to check movie or actor.Help.

Comment: Why does `turman__john` has two underscores in `starsin/2` but only one in `exists/1`?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check if the item you query on can be unified with the first or second parameter of one of the `starsin/2` facts:

```
exists(Movie) :-
    starsin(Movie, _).
exists(Actor) :-
    starsin(_, Actor).
```

Here the underscore `_` is a variable that we do not care about.